# Qt will not link anything

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, ubuntu

I have tried this both on Ubuntu Linux and on Windows. I can not get Qt to link any of its libraries or any external libraries, I have tried just about every `LIBS += -Lpath/to/lib -llib` and `INCLUDEPATH += path/to/include/files` combination possible in my `.pro file`:

```
QT += opengl
TARGET = QtOpenGLExample
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    GLExampleWidget.cpp
HEADERS += GLWidget.h
LIBS += -L /usr/lib/ -llibQtOpenGL.so.4.6.2
```

I noticed this being a problem when I clicked "Open GL" in the project creator and it did not work then (even after I tried messing around in the .pro), before I just thought I was doing something stupid when I tried to link SFML 1.6.

P.s Does it have to do with were my project is located?:

```
/home/aperson/Projects/ComputerProgramming/C++/OpenGLExample/
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the .pro file.

Comment: Oh derp, ya that may help :-)


 [Here is the file](http://pastebin.com/sfR0nTCi)

Comment: What exact link errors are you seeing?

Comment: The generic...

:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The linker should give you a more detailed error than that: "Cannot find blah blah", "Undefined reference to blah", etc.  Also why are you telling QMake to build a console application when you want to use a QGLWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have told `qmake` that you are creating a console application in your .pro file making it ignore all the GUI libraries.  So get rid of the `CONFIG += console` line.

Answer (score 4):

It should not be

```
 LIBS += -L /usr/lib/ -llibQtOpenGL.so.4.6.2
```

but

```
 LIBS += -L /usr/lib/ -lQtOpenGL
```

Because for the linker `-lfoo` means `libfoo.so`  (and it should be able to find the right version of the file, so you don't need to tell about `4.6.2`)

Probably, you don't even need a special `LIBS` since `opengl` is mentioned in the `QT`line. But you should be sure that the `libqt4-opengl-dev` package is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I got it to work by commenting out: 

QT += opengl

and by changing the line to: 

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -llibQtOpenGL

But then it started complaining that it could not find QGLWidget.h

so I added: 

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/

But then the error came back 0.0

Comment: You shouldn't need to add any of these to the .pro file except `QT += opengl`, all OpenGL libraries and headers are pulled in from that.

Comment: @cbamber85 I tried that but it did not work, I got the same error 0.0, is there any special place I should put it into the file?

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain Probably not, but near the top is wise.  Also telling `QMake` that you want a console application might be causing it to disregard all GUI libraries.

Comment: @cbamber85 Oh dear lord I am embarrassed! It was the console thing! Do you think this affected me trying to link the external library SFML-1.6?

Comment: I have no idea what `SFML` is, what if it needs a window created - probably.  I'll add the solution as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [QtOpenGL Module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtopengl.html) :

The Qt OpenGL module makes it easy to use OpenGL in Qt applications. It provides an OpenGL widget class that can be used just like any other Qt widget, except that it opens an OpenGL display buffer where you can use the OpenGL API to render the contents.

To include the definitions of the module's classes, use the following directive:

```
 #include <QtOpenGL>
```

To link against the module, add this line to your qmake .pro file:

```
 QT += opengl
```

---

You might need to link to your opengl library. This should do :

```
 LIBS += -lGL
```

Comment: I tried that doing LIBS += -lGL it did not work. Thank you though :-D

Answer (score 1):

The project file you have seems OK. QMake should generate the corrent -l -L command for you. IMHO that is not the problem.

Are you missing the opengl/Qt4 package? Its called libqt4-opengl-dev on Ubuntu and Debian. 
See

1. http://packages.debian.org/sid/libqt4-opengl-dev
2. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=libqt4-opengl-dev

Type this on your shell to check and  install the package if needed.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep opengl
ii  libqt4-opengl                          4:4.8.0-1ubuntu11                       Qt 4 OpenGL module
$ aptitude install libqt4-opengl-dev
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do have libqt4-opengl installed (I checked using your method) :-)

Comment: Type `LANG=C make` into a terminal and paste the output here.